# Fix detached entity passed to persist in one to one relationship in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following entity mapping (unidirectional):

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ch_id", referencedColumnName = "ch_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
   private Child child;
}
```

Child entity is just the regular entity.

I want to create **parent** entity with **child**, but I have two use cases:

1. When **child** entity already exists in database
2. When **child** entity is not created in database yet

when I go through the **second** use case, I successfully create **child** entity with **parent** entity (with help of cascade type **PERSIST**)

But when I go through the **first** use case I get

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.data.entity.Child; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.data.entity.Child
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:319)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy240.saveAll(Unknown Source)
```

How can I omit this error when I just need to link **parent** with **child** without removing **PERSIST** cascade type

In response of @Daniel Wosch comment:

Here I have **ParentBO** entity

```
public class ParentBO {
   
private Long childId;
   
// other fields

}
```

and this **childId** field is optional

so I get list of this parent BOs

```
    public void createParents(Collection<ParentBO> creationBOs) {

        List<Parent> parentsToPersistWithoutChild = creationBOs.stream()
                .map(parent -> prepareParentToPersist(parent))
                .collect(toList());

        repository.saveAll(parentsToPersist);
    }


    private Parent prepareParentToPersist(ParentBO parentBO) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        if (parentBO.getChildId != null) {
//            here I want just link child entity which already exists in DB with parent entity 
//            (child existence I've validated before)
            parent.setChild(new Child(parentBO.getChildId()));
        } else {
            Child child = new Child();
//            here I set all required fields for child entity which 
//            depends on parent fields (by business rules)
            parent.setChild(child);
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

Comment: How does your code look like to create both use cases? Especially the first one which is not working. Do you fetch the child from database first and then assign it to the parent?

Comment: I have a list of Parent entities which I need to create with child entities for every parent. And child entity may or may not be already persisted in DB

Comment: I try to not firstly fetch then but link on parent save to improve code readability

Comment: Could you post that code please? How do you link the child <-> parent? `new Child()` without saving is basically a detached entity.

Comment: I have provided pseudocode example above in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the child first in your first case from database to get it into the Hibernate session storage and to be managed by hibernate.

`new Child()` => transient entity. Then you are setting excplicitly the ID of the new child. Hibernate assumes that its an managed entity (*because if it has an ID it has to be in my state*). But that is not the case in your code. Therefore persisting the entity results in the posted exception.Detached means that it is an entity which was persisted in the past and is not longer maintained / managed by hibernate. This happens because you are manually set the ID of that entity after creating a new instance. Instead of creating a new instance, fetch the child from the database and set it to the parent.

1. Fetch the child entity first (now its managed by hibernate)
2. Set the child to the parent entity
3. Save the parent
4. Be happy :D

Comment: Thanks for your response!
But is there any chance to do it using new Child(), because I have two different services to work with child and parent and  when I fetch child entities I get BO objects instead of entity object so I cannot set the child entity explicitly ?

Comment: As I have no experience with this but what you could try is to call EntityManager.merge(child). This will add the detached entity to the persistent context and is now managed by Hibernate. **Important** You need to set the ID before calling merge. Further you need to use the returned Entity from merge for further processing (set to parent). **Don't** work with the entity you have provided to the merge function.  You need to inject the entityManager instance into your service to work with it.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know if it worked.